# Possible reasons why react-native-fs works on emulator but not on actual device

Tags: react-native

RNFS download snippet that works like a charm in emulator but not it the actual device.

Here is my snippet:

```
console.log("FILE URL: " + FILE_URL); // http://localhost:8081/server/public/sentfile/60b5a385e2416132e4e0c495_60b5a0c7e2416132e4e0c494/7gyic4f659ddsp10jvhsw2489.png
let ext = FILE_URL.split(".").pop();

const localFile = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/tmp.` + ext;
console.log("LF: " + localFile) // /data/user/0/com.neotechapp/files/tmp.png

let options = {
  fromUrl: FILE_URL,
  toFile: localFile
};


RNFS.downloadFile(options).promise
.then((res) => {
  console.log("RES: " + JSON.stringify(res))
  FileViewer.open(localFile);
})
.then((res) => {
    // success
})
.catch((err) =>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

On my actual device, it returns an error `[Error: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8081]`.

Comment: can you past the options object ?

Comment: I added options and other info that might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

you try to download a file from your local server "http://localhost:8081".

on your device, this will refer to the phone itself and not to your server.
so what you need is to use public IP instead (for example '192.168.1.2').

on windows use `ipconfig` to find your computer IP. and for linux use `ifconfig`

Comment: I see. Let me try that. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, on my debug server host and port, it is already checking the server IP and port though.

Comment: dang. never thought about that. Thank you. For testing purposes, I just added a replace localhost to my server ip.